# Отбор и Сортировка в SQL-таблице

Tags: sql-server, сортировка

Добрый день! Моя SQL-таблица состоит из столбцов **[оборудование][состояние][комментарий][дата]**. В столбце оборудование приборы: под кодом от 1 до 50,
Столбец состояние: вкл, выкл, 1 скорость,2 скорость. Столбец комментарий: произвольный текст. Столбец дата: время изменения состояния. Любое изменение состояние прибора фиксируется новой записью будь оно включено, поставлено на разную скорость или выключено. Вопрос такой: как из этой таблицы отобразить текущее последнее состояние всех исключительно включенных приборов?

Comment: Самое простое (но не самое эффективное) - получить в подзапросе для каждого прибора время последнего изменения состояния, и отбирать записи по нему и состоянию.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
  from (
    select A.*,
           row_number() over(partition by [оборудование] order by [дата] desc) RN
      from table A
  ) B
  where RN=1
```